# discord py Отправка сообщения в определённое время

Tags: discord, discord.py

Всем привет. Надеюсь я смогу получить ответ на свой вопрос

У меня есть команда /settime @user время
Когда я ввожу /settime @nick 13
В базу данных записывается 13 в сроку alerttime

Как я могу реализовать чтобы каждый день бот писал в ЛС в определённое время из базы данных сообщение.

То есть вот например есть 4 человека с установленным временем, и каждому в своё время каждый день бот будет писать сообщение.

Answer (score 0):

Вам ещё нужно записывать в БД время отправки первого сообщения рассылки, например через time `int(time.time())`. Для проверки можно использовать `tasks.loop` ([вот пример](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/background_task.py)). И в проверке сравнивать текущее время со временем в БД, и есть оно больше на время указанное пользователем (надо время перевести в секунды), то писать ему сообщение. А что бы первый раз написать сообщение пользователю надо написать отдельную функции.

Comment: Функцию в команде отправки сообщения и записи времени отправки в бд?